# Unity3d MYSQL large objects upload

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I`m currently developing a videogame that needs to upload levels, records, and some other large data strunctures to a MySQL database . I parse those objects to an hex string and upload the data to my database througth a WWW post in Unity3D as varbinary.

```
object codedLevel = SaveGame.codedLevel;
byte[] codedLevelBin = ObjectToByteArray(codedLevel);
string codedLevelStr = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString (codedLevelBin).Replace("-", "");
```

Since the length of the url is limited in size, I have to split the hex string , upload it in parts and merge the parts again on download.

```
int partSize = 2000; 
for( int i= 0; i <= codedLevelStr.Length   ;i = i+partSize){
    string part = "";

    if (codedLevelStr.Length - i > partSize)
        part = codedLevelStr.Substring (i, partSize);
    else if (codedLevelStr.Length < partSize)
        part = codedLevelStr;
    else
        part = codedLevelStr.Substring (i);
    codedLevelLengthParts = codedLevelLengthParts + part.Length;
    //This connects to a server side php script that will add the level to a MySQL DB.
    // Supply it with a string representing the level
    string hash = Md5Sum(User + part+ i + LVLName +  secretKey);

    string post_url = addLevelURL+ "&LVL=" + part + "&name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(User)  + "&part=" + i/partSize + "&LVLName=" + WWW.EscapeURL(LVLName) + "&hash=" + hash;

    // Post the URL to the site and create a download object to get the result.
    WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);
    yield return hs_post; // Wait until the download is do 
}
```

How I can upload all the object codedLevel from C# script in Unity3D¿

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the length of the url is limited in size, I have to split the
>   hex string , upload it in parts and merge the parts again on download.

Only the `GET` method has a limited length which is `2048` characters and you are currently using the `GET` method for your request.

This should be done with the `POST` method with the help of the `WWWForm` class.

Let's say you want to send the player's `name`, `age` and `score`, We can encode it with the code below:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("name", "Charles");
form.AddField("age", 29);
form.AddField("scrore", 67);
```

Add the player's profile picture or array data of some kind?

```
byte[] bytes = playerProfilePic;
form.AddBinaryData("profilePic", bytes, "profilePic.png", "image/png");
```

or

```
form.AddBinaryData("profilePic", bytes);
```

Now, let's send this to the Server.

```
WWW connection = new WWW(url, form);
yield return connection;
```

That's it. You don't need to send this piece by piece with a `for` loop.